# Doctrine + apigility: always 403 Forbidden

Tags: php, zend-framework, doctrine-orm, oauth-2.0, laminas-api-tools

I have a apigility backend running, integrated with doctrine.
When I do a `POST http://localhost:8080/oauth` with the following body:

```
{
  "grant_type": "password",
  "username": "jeff",
  "password": "test234",
  "client_id": "testclient"
}
```

I get a response like this:

```
{
  "access_token": "b10bee7e1b70d2cbb0e95f77caeac3b61707032c",
  "expires_in": 3600,
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "scope": "DbAPI",
  "refresh_token": "bb440c03bd8df030615d6deaa35ed9b6ace84675"
}
```

Which is correct.
Next, I do a `GET http://localhost:8080/oauth/resource`, with the following headers:

`accept: application/json`
`origin: http://localhost:4200` (my frontend, as allowed by `zfr-cors`)
`authorization: Bearer b10bee7e1b70d2cbb0e95f77caeac3b61707032c`

I get a response like this:

```
{
  "success": true,
  "message": "You accessed my APIs!"
}
```

Which is also correct!

BUT, when I do a request to `GET http://localhost:8080/user` (with the same headers as the request to `/oauth/resource`), I get a response like this:

```
{
  "type": "http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html",
  "title": "Forbidden",
  "status": 403,
  "detail": "Forbidden"
}
```

Which is NOT correct. When I disable authentication in the apigility web-ui, I get the correct response, which is an array of Users.

So, **only `/oauth/resource` returns the correct info, the rest (when auth is activated) always returns a 403, even when using the correct `access_token`)**.

Is there any apigility/doctrine guru that can help me out?

As always, if you need more code snippets / info / screenshots, please let me know!

Comment: Hi Jeff, have you configured each API (e.g. `/users`) to require authentication (`oauth2_doctrine (oauth2)` in dropdown)?

Comment: Hi rkeet! Yes, every API has that specific auth option selected. Also, in the authentication tab, every (possible) method (GET, POST, etc) is checked.

Comment: Guessing Authorization tab here ;) But ok, that's good. Next, I'm assuming your using `api-skeletons/zf-oauth2-doctrine` to handle your authentication? If yes, have you updated the config? Dist files in module itself give you `oauth2.doctrine-orm.global.php` and `oauth2.global.php`. Next, having module `zfcampus/zf-mvc-auth` gives `zf-mvc-auth-oauth2-override.global.php` as config file. Have you got all of this? What do and don't you have?

Comment: (Oh, have you enabled developer mode? (terminal: `composer development-enable`) and have you made sure the default cache is removed from `data/cache` and `data/DoctrineORMMOdule/Proxy`?)